# Can't use npm installed packages from command line

Tags: command-line, npm

I installed node.js and npm recently and was trying to install the learnyounode npm package using `sudo npm install -g learnyounode`, but after installing I am not able to access it from command line. When I run `learnyounode` I am getting

> /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

I checked `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to find `learnyounode` folder in it, not only learnyounode, I am not able to access any npm packages from command line. I am using npm 1.3.10 and node.js 0.10.25.

Comment: apparently , it's not finding node or node lib in my path . i fixed it by creating a symlink ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Comment: Yeah, I've done that too. It's quite annoying that the binary is called nodejs while most of the stuff always assumes node.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install like this, then you don't need the sym link. If I were you I'd delete it, because you might not get the updates automatically and always have to "relink" it.

Try it like this:

```
aptitude install nodejs
apt-get install npm
aptitude install nodejs-legacy
```

Then try to install npm packages

```
npm install -g bunyan
npm install -g forever
```

Comment: you deserve at least +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment section, create a link to fix the problem:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Alternatively, as mentioned in [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660763/grunt-cli-dont-work), you can also use `update-alternatives` to do the job:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

Either way, it should now work fine.

[source](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911)