# grunt-cli doesn't work

Tags: command-line, nodejs, grunt

I have the latest stable `node.js`. It works, npm works, nvc works.

When I try to install grunt I install `grunt-cli`, I install grunt in a local folder and after typing `grunt` or `grunt --version` or `grunt -h` etc I get this:

```
$ grunt --version 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I tried adding path but since I am new to Linux I might have done it wrong.

This is the report from installing grunt-cli:

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt   
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7) 
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

feel free to talk to me like you would talk to a child...
thanks!

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Do `type -a node nodejs`. What do you see?

Comment: type -a node nodejs
bash: type: node: not found
nodejs is /usr/bin/nodejs

Comment: Do you know what to change now?

Comment: you know what, I dont. thats why I asked you to asume i was 3y old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y'know what, my last comment was pretty snarky. Apologies.

You have node.js installed, except the binary is called `nodejs` and grunt is assuming it's `node`.

There's a built-in way to create aliases to programs: [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

After that, grunt should be able to find `node` that points to `nodejs`